# OLED display as the main screen?

Tags: display

Firstly, please forgive me if this is a dumb question.  I'm new to Raspberries and am conducting some blue sky thinking.  I have in mind to build a low-power, lightweight and very minimal Unix machine as a portable battery-powered dairy when hiking.  I know the easiest (and probably most practical) thing to do would be to use a notepad and pen, but ... well ... I prefer to type.

I'm toying with buying a Raspberry Pi Zero, a 2.7" OLED display and a plug-in keyboard. (I may even try to adapt an old ThinkOutside Palm folding keyboard, provided the Pi Zero can accept a serial connector, but that's another question.)

For now, my question is: Can I use a mini OLED display as the device's main display or can one only be used as a peripheral to show particular information?  Everywhere I've looked indicates an OLED display is a peripheral display.